# How to execute a macro until we encounter a character

Tags: macro

How can I repeat the execution of a macro until a character is encountered?

For example (just an example, it's not the original problem I want you to solve)
I want to convert a `CAPITAL_CAMEL_CASE` to `Sentence case` in the following line using the macro as follows:
`^7wviwu~`, now  since I have `Some_string_constant`, I want to replace `_` with a  
(space), for that _ have written another macro `f_r<space>`.

```
private static final String SOME_STRING_CONSTANT = "SOME_STRING_CONSTANT";
```

Now different lines have different number of `_` and I need to carefully manually count and repeat the second macro.
How can I repeat second macro until I encounter `"` as I am trying to execute macro only on the string enclosed in `"`?

**Note:** I am using a vim plugin in IDE which does not support a replacement for a selection.

Comment: tpope's abolish plugin has support for changing from cases

Comment: Depends on whether IDE supports vim plugins, which is probably not the case

Answer (score 2):

In vim (not sure about other IDE plugins)

- When there is a "fail" in a macro it stops execution.
- When `f<char>` can't find next char it "fails".

So you can

1. Create a macro `@r` that does only `f_r<space>`.
2. Use it in other macro `@q` that executes `@r` with a large count.
3. Or use it in `:normal` command if your IDE supports it.

### Example:

[image]

### PS, simpler sequences

Macro:

```
qqvi"u~h100@rq
```

Normal command:

```
:'<,'>normal! vi"u~h100@r
```

where `@r` is `qrf_r q`

Comment: Another option would be a recursive macro that repeats the `f_r ` step: `qrqqrf_r @rq`, I think

Comment: Yes indeed. I don't like recursive macros thus didn't even think about them ;)